# Errors when importing someone else's projects - Android/Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse for about 6 months now, and I noticed that I rarely can import someone else's project into Eclipse. I get so many errors in many files. For example, I tried to import a friend's project that I know works just fine, but I get a lot of "R" errors, like Eclipse can't recognize "R" as a field, and then other weird ones like ActionBarActivity is not recognized or an entire imports like android.support.v4.app.Fragment that visually are in the library but are not being recognized by Eclipse as being there, and I check them and they are definitely marked "Is library" and added properly to the project. Anyone know why this is or how to fix? It's frustrating because to learn, sometimes you need to see someone else's app run first, then look at their code, but you can't. Thanks in advance.

My usual way of importing a project is to do File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace. Also, I have tried cleaning the project, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to the help of everyone of this post, and others on another post, the problem was finally fixed and took several steps.

1. Turns out that the ActionBarActivity error had a quick fix (hover over it, you get quick fix options) of importing the appcompat_v7 library. I never chose that before, because I thought it was already installed, hence the conflict with android-support-v4.jar (meaning there were doubles of that library), but I chose to import it anyway and that error went away.
2. But I discovered that android-support-v4.jar was actually a component of appcompat_v7, so that was causing the "Jar mismatch!" error in the console. So I deleted android-support-v4.jar from the libs folder, and the jar mismatch went away.
3. Lastly, my layout files were all not being recognized, even though I knew the variable names were all correct. So the error was from when I tried to refresh my imports in the very beginning of the problem (using shift+command+O), thinking it was an import problem (which it was), but at that time, refreshing did nothing. BUT... Eclipse took away import `com.laurengariepy.android.gridimagesearch.R;` and replaced it with `android.R;`, which is what was causing all the layout errors. So once I put that `com.laurengariepy.android.gridimagesearch.R;` back, then all errors went away.

So the take-away to this story, is be careful with Eclipse version 22.6. The auto-import of the appcompat_v7 library will cause a lot of trouble when you try to import other people's projects, because they were likely not created in an IDE with appcompat_v7 already there.

Answer (score 0):

try this File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into WorkSpace ->then browse-> select your project->make sure the checkBox"copy the project into workSpace" is marked

Comment: thanks Maxwell for the suggestion, but it did not work.

Comment: try to clean the project,then android tools-> fix project properties. Still find an error try to restart your eclipse

Comment: Did you import all the packages ??

Comment: darn, this did not work either. i tried all those 3 steps. :/

Comment: what do you mean import the packages? I got my friend's project from Github as a zip file, I unzipped it and then chose the project folder when I imported. is there normally another step to take when importing someone else's project?

Comment: Then may be the problem is with your resource files.check drawable,layout folders and make sure that naming and layout are in proper way.

Comment: Clean project and update your sdk.When you deleting the project tick out on check box delete project contents first of all check manually if this project not contain in your workspace

Comment: The only thing is, the project works fine on my friend's computer, so i think all the files are named right (with the right resources). my other guess was maybe I did not have all my proper SDK packages installed, but I checked and the support packages are all installed...

Comment: @Zeeshan, if i check that checkbox it only removes it completely from my computer, which i did try before, then re-downloaded from Github, but it had the same problem.

Comment: Check your project.properties file and manifest.xml file targetsdk version is available in your sdk and all are same

Comment: thanks Zeeshan, i checked those 2 files, they have the same API level (16) and every package under my SDK API 16 is installed. still have the problem. :/ but in the other post, it said now there is a Jar Mismatch... that somehow apcompat_v7 and android-support-v4.jar are in conflict. should i try to delete one of them? the file path is from some folder in my workspace (not the original friend's project folder), so this must be drawing from my workspace library.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Build Path. In the Android Section, try using some other API level click on Apply and after your project finishes with the building workspace, again revert back to the original API and click on OK.

Also check for any Build Path errors.

Comment: thanks Vikram, do you mean change the API level in the Android Manifest? Also... how do I find Build Path errors? (sorry, I am a beginner).

Comment: No, NOT in the Android Manifest. In the Android section of Build Path. You can go to build path configuration (by right clicking your project). Let me know if you require more inputs.

Comment: ah okay thanks. okay, i went to Build Path - Configure, and noticed in the Android section that the apcompat_v7 library was red. so i re-added that library, and deleted the red one. the green one came up next to the new apcompat_v7 but then when I clicked "apply" i got a "jar mismatch! fix your dependencies" in the console error. i also chose a new API level.

Comment: Here is more about the error: 'Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time). All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.' But when i look into the dependencies folder, there is only apcompat_v7, there is no android-support-v4.jar.

Comment: Does your apcompat_v7 library contain any android-support-v4.jar file?

Comment: AH, yes it does! but the thing is, these are auto-imported with the latest Eclipse update 22.6 (which i totally hate, btw).. is there a way to get rid of that? what is the proper way do you think?

Comment: Go to Configure Build Path section again, in the Order and Export Tab check the checkbox for Android Private Libraries and uncheck for the reference library shown there.

Comment: okay, I went there and the Private Libraries was already checked, but I unchecked the Android Dependencies... then cleaned again, and even restarted Eclipse, but the same errors are there, and i still see both libraries in their folders. the Android Dependencies still shows the appcompat_v7. then i checked the place again and the Android Dependencies got rechecked automatically when I restarted Eclipse. but then again, it didn't make any difference unchecked before, i noticed.

Comment: should i just try to delete the android-support-v4.jar file?

Comment: Okay, i tried to just delete the android-support-v4.jar file from my libs folder. cleaned the project. i don't get the "Jar mismatch!" error anymore, but all those other errors are still there (can't resolve ActionBarActivity or R). ugh...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Wasn't there at my desk.
For those errors, try importing the right R.java file.

Comment: thanks Vikram, no worries. ended up that the ActionBarActivity had a "quick fix" of importing the appcompat_v7, which i tried, and it fixed that problem, but then the layout files were not recognized, which was because when i refreshed my imports at the beginning of this, Eclipse snuck in an 'import android.R;' one, which was not right. so changing that back to the 'import package_name.R;' fixed it finally. Whew!! that was a doozy.

Comment: So all your issues got resolved? If yes, and you feel my answer/comments helped you in anyway, please upvote and accept the answer to your question.

Comment: hi Vikram, actually it was not the build path or API, it was a library conflict issue. but thanks for troubleshooting with me. i posted the story with answer and remedy below, i will check as right answer soon (must wait 2 days). you comment about the R.java file was partially correct, but not the entire answer. I upvoted that comment.